# Identar XML desde PHP

Tags: xml

Como puedo extraer el XML y agregarle una identacion para que quede en un formato agradable a la vista.
Ejemplo:

```
<metadata>
    <data>Dato1</data>
    <data2>Dato2</data2>
    <data3>Dato3</data3>
<metadata>
```

Comment: Hola Cometa. Puedes explicar mejor? De donde lo sacas? Cómo? a donde lo quieres extraer?

Comment: Mira lo que pasa es que tengo un xml que tiene toda la informacion pero no se encuentra agradable a la vista quiero saber si puedo aplicarle una identacion a ese XML

Comment: Un xml deberia tener identacion automatica si tiene todas las etiquetas bien cerradas. Mira a ver si es eso. si no, pega el texto en http://xmlbeautifier.com/ para que te lo "ponga bonito"

Comment: La idea es hacerlo automatico a traves de php

Comment: La idea es que expliques mejor lo que quieres. Donde lo vas a pegar, en una web? en que elemento HTML? de donde lo sacas? de un fichero ¿?

Comment: Tengo un archivo XML que esta con toda la informacion pero no se encuentra en un formato agradable(por asi decirlo todo junto sin saltos de linea) quiero aplicarle una identacion y volver a guardarlo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615422/php-xml-how-to-output-nice-format checa esta pregunta en SO Ingles.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la extencion tidy y mandar el resultado al archivo.

```html
<?php
$config = array(
           'indent'         => true,
           'wrap'           => 200,
           'output-xml' => true,
           'input-xml' => true
           );

$file = "/home/xxx/Documentos/prueba.xml";
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString(file_get_contents($file), $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

echo $tidy;
```

solo debes sobre escribir el archivo el codigo anterior solo lo imprime.

saludos